# Imprimir dígitos leds en horizontal

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Ejemplo de impresión de números leds:

   ```
   # ### ### # # ### ### ### ### ### ### 
   #   #   # # # #   #     # # # # # # # 
   # ### ### ### ### ###   # ### ### # # 
   # #     #   #   # # #   # # #   # # # 
   # ### ###   # ### ###   # ### ### ###
   ```
2. Aquí almaceno en una lista cada uno de los numeros 0-9:

```
leds=['''
###
# #
# #
# #
###''','''
  #
  #
  #
  #
  #''','''
###
  #
###
#
###''','''
###
  #
###
  #
###''','''
# #
# #
###
  #
  #''','''
###
#
###
  #
###''','''
###
#
###
# #
###''','''
###
  #
  #
  #
  #''','''
###
# #
###
# #
###''','''
###
# #
###
  #
###''']
```

3. Pido al usuario un número para almacenarlo como lista:

   lista = list(input('Dame un número: '))
4. Inicializo una lista que me ayudará a convertir la entrada del usuario a enteros:

   numeroLista=[]
5. Itero cada número en la lista del usuario, convirtiendo cada elemento a enteros de esta manera obtengo el número a imprimir en led:

   for numero in lista:
   numeroLista.append(int(numero))
6. Imprimo cada dígito identificado en la lista led:

   for digito in numeroLista:
   print(leds[digito])
7. Ésta es la salida que obtengo:

   Dame un número: 123

Y debería ser en horizontal. Ya he probado integrar al `print end=''`, al igual que con `strip()` y no consigo obtener el resultado deseado.

Siento que mi error está en cómo almaceno inicialmente los patrones de los dígitos en led.

Comment: si lo que quieres es hacer impresion en horizontal, tienes que utilizar librerias tipo ncurses, O hacer que tu programa imprima cada linea de cada numero, esto es, si cada numero esta compuesto por 5 lineas, primero tienes que dibujar la primera linea de TODOS los numeros. Luego la segunda linea de Todos... y asi hasta acabar las 5 lineas.

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu código funcione debes agregar cada línea del dígito a las líneas que serán impresas.

He optado por hacerlo como una nueva matriz para que luego pueda unir las piezas mediante un espacio en blanco:

```
lista = list(input('Dame un número: '))

numeroLista = [[], [], [], [], [], []]

for numero in lista:
    for num, linea in enumerate(leds[int(numero)].splitlines()):
        numeroLista[num].append(linea)

for linea in numeroLista:
    print(" ".join(linea))
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
$ python3 pr.py
Dame un número: 1234567890
         
  # ### ### # # ### ### ### ### ### ###
  #   #   # # # #   #     # # # # # # #
  # ### ### ### ### ###   # ### ### # #
  # #     #   #   # # #   # # #   # # #
  # ### ###   # ### ###   # ### ### ###
```

PD: Para que te funcione correctamente deberás rellenar los espacios en blanco a la derecha de los caracteres 2, 5 y 6.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de sencilla de hacerlo es usando ciclos y matrices. Lo único que necesitas es la librería `numpy` para manejar arreglos. Te comparto el código y te explico paso a paso como funciona. Solo son 3 ciclos anidados

```
import numpy as np
lista = [
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1],]),
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1],])
]

cifra = list(input('Ingresa un numero: '))

for i in range(5):
    print('\n', end='')
    for j in range(len(cifra)):
        print(' ', end='') 
        for k in range(3):
            if lista[int(cifra[j])][i][k]:
                print('#', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')
```

#### Paso 1

La importación de `numpy`, que como ya dije sirve para manejar arreglos

#### Paso 2

Creas una lista de arreglos de tamaño 5x3 (5 corresponde a filas, 3 a columnas) donde cada fila tiene 3 elementos que son los puntos que forman un numero. Por ejemplo, el numero `1` que corresponde al segundo arreglo de la lista es:

```
np.array([
[0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1],])
```

Como puedes observar los "1" forman el numero. Por simplicidad escribo sin saltos de linea.

#### Paso 3

Convertimos el numero ingresado por el usuario en una lista donde cada numero es un elemento:

```
cifra = list(input('Ingresa un numero: '))
```

#### Paso 4

Basicamente recorremos linea a linea todos los numeros ingresados. Por ejemplo si escribes el numero 12, recorre la primera linea del numero 1 y despues la primera linea del numero 2, posteriormente la segunda linea de cada numero y asi sucesivamente.

```
for i in range(5):
    print('\n', end='')
    for j in range(len(cifra)):
        print(' ', end='') 
        for k in range(3):
            if lista[int(cifra[j])][i][k]:
                print('#', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')
```

El ciclo `for` de mas afuera se ejecuta 5 veces (de 0 a 4), cada iteración corresponde a una fila (linea). Dentro de ese ciclo `for` esta otro que se ejecuta dependiendo del numero de cifras ingresadas. El ultimo cilo `for` solamente recorre en cada numero los 3 valores de cada linea e imprime `#` si el valor es 1 o   si es 0.

#### Resultados

El Resultado de ingresar el numero `12345`:

```
   # ### ### # # ###
   #   #   # # # #
   # ### ### ### ###
   # #     #   #   #
   # ### ###   # ###
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi alternativa es crear una lista (`lineas`) donde almaceno sublistas. Cada sublista corresponde a un dígito del valor ingresado y contiene la representación de dicho digito (tomada de `leds`).

Luego recorro la lista `lineas` 5 veces. En cada pasado tomo la línea i-esima de la representación de cada digito.

```
cifra ="1234567890"

lineas=[leds[int(digito)].split("\n") for digito in cifra]
[print(" ".join([lista[linea] for lista in lineas])) for linea in range(1,6)]
```

produce:

```
  # ### ### # # ### ### ### ### ### ###
  #   #   # # # #.. #..   # # # # # # #
  # ### ### ### ### ###   # ### ### # #
  # # .   #   #   # # #   # # #   # # #
  # ### ###   # ### ###   # ### ### ###
```

Nota: puse "." en la representación para asegurar que todos los componentes sean del mismo largo. En caso contrario, se desalinea.